# Регулярные выражение, группирующие скобки

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Я из текста вытаскиваю следующий текст `IDs: 99751, 99744, 99749, 99750`, для этого я использую регулярное выражение `IDs: (?:\d+[, \n]{1,2}){1,6}`, но проблема в том, что я хочу в итоге список `[99751, 99744, 99749, 99750]`, а получаю только подходящую строку `IDs: 99751, 99744, 99749, 99750`, как это можно исправить?

В тексте могут быть другие числа.

`Шаблон задачи 1 - Необходимые меры (вариантов: 4) IDs: 99751, 99744, 99749, 99750 Поле ввода Текст задачи: Длина охотничьей собаки в спокойном состоянии составляет 57 см, однако в указательной стойке длина собаки от кончика носа до кончика хвоста увеличивается до 75 см. Сколько напряженных охотничьих собак поместится между двумя людьми, соблюдающими минимально рекомендуемую социальную дистанцию? В ответе запишите только целое число. Баллы: 24 Шаблон задачи 2 - Живые часы (вариантов: 4) IDs: 100026, 100024, 100023, 100025 Несколько из нескольких Текст задачи: Представьте, что вы оказались в саду Карла Линнея. На клумбе закрыты все цветки, кроме мака, белой лилии и ястребинки зонтичной. Сколько же сейчас времени? При ответе на вопрос пользуйтесь таблицей. Баллы: 20`

Comment: приведите в вопросе пример текста

Comment: @MaxU я добавил, просто числа спарсить не получится.

Comment: Сначала вы получили (спарсили) строку `"IDs: 99751, 99744, 99749, 99750"`. В своем ответе я показал как уже из этой строки получить все числа . В итоге две итерации и макстимально простые регулярные выражения

Comment: А, невероятно, спасибо :)

Comment: Я почему-то не понял сначала ваш ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего из полученной строки спарсить все числа:

```
parsed_string = "IDs: 99751, 99744, 99749, 99750"
res = re.findall("(\d+)", parsed_string)
```

результат:

```
In [323]: res
Out[323]: ['99751', '99744', '99749', '99750']
```